# How to reset location of default Windows 10 application windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, appearance

I've recently been noticing my explorer and control panel windows slowly creeping down into the lower right corner of my monitor. I was wondering if there was anyway of resetting the default location of default Windows 10 application windows. I've seen a few posts on here about deleting LastXPos / LastYPos from the registry editor, but can't find the default Win 10 apps in here, and don't even know if they track window location like this.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I simply make sure the App is where I want and the size I want before closing. That usually works.

Comment: Perhaps make an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script that repositions the windows for you.